# Using AppleScript, how does one create a clickable link to a web site in a Numbers cell?

Tags: applescript, numbers

I am doing some automation work using Numbers to track web page views.

My test script is something like the following:

```
set myURL to "https://mywebpage.com"
tell application "Numbers"
   tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
      add row below last row
      tell last row
         set value of first cell to current date
         set value of second cell to myURL
         -- Here I want to tell the second cell to make itself a link to a Webpage
      end tell
   end tell
end tell
```

I've tried using UI automation to select the menu "Format > Add Link > Webpage" but that menu item is only enabled if the text in the cell is selected.

So I guess unless there's a better way to make the value a link, the question may come down how to select the text inside a cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applescript and Numbers don't really offer access to text selection, but it looks like you're comfortable using the entire cell for your link. While  UI scripting can solve such a problem, most spreadsheets offer functions of their own which applescript can access.

Numbers provides a `hyperlink` [function](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/9.1/#/ffa596a1c7) which lets you create a link in a cell, and optionally, set the displayed text. I have included example code for both options and show the desired function.

The url must include the protocol (e.g. https) and be enclosed in quotes. Because you're setting it in an applescript, the quotes must be escaped.

```
set myURL to "https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/9.1/#/ffa596a1c7"
set myPageTitle to "Formulas and Functions Help" -- optional

tell application "Numbers"
    tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
        
        set value of cell 1 of row 10 to "=hyperlink(\"" & myURL & "\")"
    --> HYPERLINK("https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/9.1/#/ffa596a1c7")

        set value of cell 1 of row 10 to "=hyperlink(\"" & myURL & "\",\"" & myPageTitle & "\")" -- with optional
    --> HYPERLINK("https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/9.1/#/ffa596a1c7","Formulas and Functions Help") -- contents of cell
        
        set alignment of cell 1 of row 10 to left
        
    end tell
end tell
```

I'll leave it to you to work out your of adding rows, etc….

Comment: Perfect!  I'm not all that familiar with scripting Numbers, so that would have taken me a long time to figure out. I've mostly worked with Excel to do stuff like this.   Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. It can be a challenge finding documentation for applescript with numbers but there is a [site](https://iworkautomation.com/) that offers some example scripts.

Answer (score 1):

First add an `activate` *command* to the `tell application "Numbers"` *block* so **Numbers** is frontmost, then after the `tell application "Numbers"` *block* add the following:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke return using option down
    keystroke "a" using command down
    keystroke "k" using command down
    keystroke return
end tell
```

This will set focus into the last `cell` modified, in this case the one with the **URL**,and select the *text* and make it a *link*.

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, and the *code* in the **OP** was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

If necessary, add a `delay` *command* between the `keystroke` *commands*, e.g.: `delay 0.1`

Another method is to make a *handler* and use it as in this example:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set myURL to "https://mywebpage.com"
tell application "Numbers"
    tell table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
        add row below last row
        tell last row
            set value of first cell to current date
            set value of second cell to myURL
        end tell
    end tell
    activate
    my makeWebpageLink()
end tell

to makeWebpageLink()
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke return using option down
        keystroke "a" using command down
        keystroke "k" using command down
        keystroke return
    end tell
end makeWebpageLink
```

Comment: This works too.  Nice to see alternate techniques.  Thanks!